# Advice on fitting curve to three-pooled plant decomposition model in r

Tags: r, biostatistics, curve-fitting, nonlinear, nls

I have just finished running a plant decomposition experiment measuring the decomposition of pine needles across climate and lithological types. We have mass loss, plant chemistry data (c, n, labile carbon, cellulose, hemicellulose, and lignin), and CDI (climate decomposition index).  I will be fitting the three pooled model to mass loss data to calculate decomposition rate (k1,2,3) as I also have the litter chemistry data (labile carbon, cellulose, hemicellulose, and lignin content) according to Adair et al., 2008 (see below equation).

```
M t =M1× exp(−k1× CDI ×t)+M2× exp[−k2× CDI ×t]+M3× exp(−k3× CDI ×t)
```

where Mt = mass at time t, m1= initial labile carbon content (%), m2 = holocellulose content, m3 = lignin content. and CDI = climate decomposition index. These rates will then be modeled time with a generalized linear mixed-effect model.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to a package/ packages that can be used to fit this model over multiple sites and how to generate predictions from this?  I am happy to do the necessary reading but am struggling to find the correct resources.

[image: Example data structure, this covers two experiments so it will be split into two files of normal and transplant]

Comment: I have managed to fit the curve to one sight using:   eqtn <- function(m1,k1,cdi,t,m2,k2,m3,k3){(m1*exp(-k1*cdi*t)+
                                             m2*exp(-k2*cdi*t)+
                                             m3*exp(-k3*cdi*t))}                              nls(mass_remaining_percent ~ eqtn(scf_mean_initial,k1,cdi_mean,days_between,
                                  holocellulose_mean_initial,k2,lignin_mean_initial,k3),
    start = list(k1 = 0.0007,k2 = 0.0005, k3= 0.0001), data = a.3_pooled_data)                    Does anyone know how to apply this over sites (field_code)

Comment: Hi, there are blind and visually impaired users of this 
site who interact with it using screen readers. So please show data excerpt as text, not as an image!